# VHDL: array of items that is can be only '0' or '1', and not ''X', 'L', 'H', or 'U' used in case statement?

Tags: vhdl

Is there a data type in VHDL that is an array like a "std_logic_vector", but instead of having all having 9 possible states:

```
'U': uninitialized. This signal hasn't been set yet. 
'X': unknown. Impossible to determine this value/result. 
'0': logic 0 
'1': logic 1 
'Z': High Impedance 
'W': Weak signal, can't tell if it should be 0 or 1. 
'L': Weak signal that should probably go to 0 
'H': Weak signal that should probably go to 1 
'-': Don't care.
```

has only two possible states:

```
'0': logic 0 
'1': logic 1
```

The reason why I ask this is because i'm looking for the VHDL equivalent of the verilog case statement.  Verilog Example:

```
module m1(input a, input b, output reg[7:0] q);
wire [1:0] sel = {a, b};
always @* begin
    case(sel)
    2'b00: q = 8'd1;
    2'b01: q = 8'd2;
    2'b10: q = 8'd3;
    2'b11: q = 8'd4;
    endcase
end 
endmodule
```

In VHDL, I can do this with no problems:

```
entity m1 is
    port(
        a :in std_logic;
        b :in std_logic;
        q :out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
    );
end entity;
```

```
architecture rtl of m1 is
    signal sel :std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
begin
    sel <= a & b;

    process(sel)
    begin
        case sel is
        when "00" => q <= 1;
        when "01" => q <= 2;
        when "10" => q <= 3;
        when "11" => q <= 4;
        end case;
   end process;

end architecture;
```

The problem with this is that both Xilinx ISE and Modelsim refuse to compile this code saying that I didn't cover the states for 'X', 'U', 'L', 'H', etc...
so i need to add a "when others => q <= 'X';" statement to my VHDL....

Then, when I compile the code with Vivado, it says, "WARNING: you have a default case eventhough your full case was covered." so then I delete the "when others=>" clause of the case...

Well, this is just annoying... is there a way to get it to work in every tool without generating either an ERROR message or a bogus warning message?

My idea was to just use an array type that can be only "0" or "1" like an integer... but instead more like std_logic_vector without supporting all the other logic states that mess up the case select and require the "when others =>" clause....

possible? its there a VHDL data type like this already built in?  an array of only '0' or '1' and nothing else specifically for catatentating together and being used as a case selection?  integer types don't have 'U' or 'X', but are perfectly ok to use in a VHDL case... i'm wondering if the same holds for an array type of ('0', '1')?

Comment: The others case can be useful in simulation if you've got some odd signals coming in, you'll then put XXs on Q - which is useful to see on a waveform. A lot of people often omit the `when "11"` case, and just put the final case in `when others`, but this covers errors states also - possibly masking an error. This is the same if you convert the slv to a bitvector.

Answer (score 1):

You should stick with `std_logic` and `std_logic_vector`, an other post is presenting the differences: [When to use STD_LOGIC over BIT in VHDL](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/51848/when-to-use-std-logic-over-bit-in-vhdl)

I think your problem comes (also) from the fact that you are putting an `integer` into a `std_logic_vector`. You should use the conversion functions:

- `to_unsigned(arg: natural, size: natural) return unsigned`
- `std_logic_vector(arg: signed or unsigned) return std_logic_vector`

Which leads you to:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all; --DO NOT FORGET THIS LIBRARY TO USE THE CONVERSION FUNCTION

entity m1 is
    port(
        a :in std_logic;
        b :in std_logic;
        q :out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
    );
end entity;

architecture rtl of m1 is
    signal sel :std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
begin
    sel <= a & b;

    process(sel)
    begin
        case sel is
        when "00" => q <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(1,q'length));
        when "01" => q <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(2,q'length));
        when "10" => q <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(3,q'length));
        when "11" => q <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(4,q'length));
        when others => q <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(1,q'length));
        end case;
   end process;

end architecture;
```

Comment: The case statement evaluating `sel` does no have an **others** choice, the issue prompting the OP's question. IEEE Std 1076-2008 10.8 Case statement requires (in all revisions of the standard) every value of the expression `sel` be covered by the set of choices and "The choice **others** is only allowed for the last alternative and as its only choice; it stands for all values (possibly none) not given in the choices of previous alternatives."

Comment: Indeed, I corrected that mistake, and improved my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try VHDL Predefined Types from the package standard:

```
type bit is ('0', '1');
type bit_vector is array (natural range <>) of bit;

funciton to_stdlogicvector (b :bit_vector)  return std_logic_vector;
function to_bitvector      (s :std_ulogic_vector) return bit_vector;
```

```
architecture rtl of m1 is
    signal sel :std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
    signal bv  :bit_vector(1 downto 0);
begin
    sel <= a & b;
    bv  <= to_bitvector(sel);

    process(bv)
    begin
        case bv is
        when "00" => q <= 1;
        when "01" => q <= 2;
        when "10" => q <= 3;
        when "11" => q <= 4;
        end case;
   end process;

end architecture;
```

Comment: It isn't possible to specify the type of an abstract literal  as that of an array type (`q`). This is where air78's answer comes from using conversion from an abstract literal (a number) of  type natural to std_logic_vector.